# HTMLのインライン修飾機能：elements.style

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

２つの画像を参照してください。

Aをお手本にしてb要素を付け加えたいのですが、Bのようにうまいこといきません。
どのようにすればb要素を追加することができるのでしょうか。

A
[![画像の説明をここに入力][1]][1]

B
[![画像の説明をここに入力][2]][2]

画像を追加します。

[![画像の説明をここに入力][3]][3]

Htmlの黄色枠に作者がCSS欄で記述したものを入力すればいいのでしょうか。もし、そうなら間違っているのではなく、やり方に２つの方法があると思われますが。

Comment: 「B画像のh2要素のスタイルを変える」ではなく「B画像のh2要素をb要素に変更したい」ということですか？「Aをお手本にする」ではなくて、何をどう変えたいのか具体的に例えば「画像のh2要素にwidth:200px;を適用したい」等具体的に質問を書き換えてみてください

Comment: @keitaro_so
>「B画像のh2要素のスタイルを変える」ではなく「B画像のh2要素をb要素に変更したい」ということですか？
はい　そうです。

Comment: Htmlの黄色枠に何かを追加すればいいのですが、それは作者がCSS欄に記述したものですか。もし、そうなら間違っているのではなく、方法が２つあるということでないでしょうか

Comment: 編集で追加の画像 URL が貼れていない、元々の画像 URL も削除されてしまっているようですので確認してみてください。

Comment: 画像を調整しました。

Answer (score 1):

お手本にしている画像が実行しているのは、該当の要素の「スタイル」を変更するであり、
ご自身がやりたいことが該当の要素自体を書き換えるかと思います。

やりたいことに対して、参考にしている資料が間違っています。

要素の変更をしたいのであれば
画面右側のスタイルを変更するのではなくて
左側のHTMLの画面で変更したい要素をダブルクリックして編集モードにして書き換えてみてください

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

詳しくは以下を参照
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/#type

Comment: せっかくURLの貼付をいただいたのですが、現在の私にとってまったく理解できないので読みませんでした。
＞左側のHTMLの画面で変更したい要素をダブルクリックして編集モードにして書き換え
ここの箇所の説明をできるならテキストでいただいたのですが。

Comment: テキストでは説明しているので、画像で説明してほしいということですかね？

Comment: 画像を追加して説明してみました。何かわからないところがあればご指摘ください

Comment: ＞画像を追加して説明してみました。何かわからないところがあればご指摘ください
ありがとうございます。が画像を失念されているみたいです。

Comment: いや回答に画像を追記していますよ？見えないですか？